# Can I give access to sql server+reporting services without creating a login/user for each domain account?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windowsdomainaccount

In our sqlserver 2008 database each user has a sqlserver login and sqlserver database user. When a new person joins the company the system admins set up their domain accounts but we then have to go in and create a sqlserver login with the same name as the domain user.

Is there any way to make sqlserver let people authenticated to the domain login with some given default access?

Comment: Make use of domain groups? Give the group access to the SQLServer and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Windows Domain Group (such as Domain\SQLReportingUserReaders) and add it to the relevant Reporting Services Roles.

See [Setting Permissions in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337491.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks moontear.

I created a login called DOMAIN\Domain Users and any users that already have a login use their own account but new users use this new account.